# Kotlin extension function wrong byte code generated

Tags: kotlin, jvm, inline, kotlin-extension, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

Below snippet breaks compilation due to: *Back-end (JVM) Internal error: wrong bytecode generated : no bytecode*

```
inline fun <reified T : Observable> T?.onPropertyChanged(d: CompositeDisposable? = null, crossinline callback: (T) -> Unit) = this?.run { blabla }
```

However, It works as expected If I stop inline and reified.

**Important note: This problem only occurs when inline extension published to aar, with local usage no problem at all.**

Just curious about why it happens,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's `blabla`, can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu ty for reply, it doesnt matter. I also removed all lines so it was just an empty function.

Comment: That might be a problem with aar packaging probably, report it at https://kotl.in/issue